# "TypeError: functions.firestore.collection is not a function"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Looking through the Firestore documentation, I see many examples of `functions.firestore.document` but I don't see any examples of `functions.firestore.collection`. Firestore syntax is

```
firebase.firestore().collection('...').doc('...')
```

I get an error message with

```
firebase.firestore().document('...')
```

Yet in Cloud Functions with this code:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore.collection('...').doc('...').onUpdate(event => {
```

on deploy I get an error message:

```
TypeError: functions.firestore.collection is not a function
```

When I change the code to

```
exports.getWatsonTokenFirestore = functions.firestore.document('...').onUpdate(event => {
```

I don't get an error message on deploy.

Why does Cloud Functions appear to have a different data structure than Cloud Firestore?

Here's my full Cloud Function. My collection is `User_Login_Event` and my document is `Toggle_Value`:

```
    exports.getWatsonTokenFS = functions.firestore.document('User_Login_Event/{Toggle_Value}').onUpdate(event => {
              var username = 'TDK',
              password = 'swordfish',
              url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api';
              request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {
admin.firestore().collection('IBM_Watson_Token').document('Token_Value').update('token');
              });
              return 0; // prevents an error message "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"
            });
```

The function deploys without error but when it executes I get this error message:

```
TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function
```

I'm confused as `firebase.firestore` isn't in my Cloud Function. It's in my Angular front-end code in various places, without a problem. What is this error message referring to? I tried changing the line

```
admin.firestore().collection('IBM_Watson_Token').document('Token_Value').update('token');
```

to

```
firebase.firestore().collection('IBM_Watson_Token').document('Token_Value').update('token');
```

and to

```
console.log("getWatsonTokenFS response");
```

but I got the same error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  You should format it as...

```
exports.getWatsonTokenFirestore = functions.firestore.document('myCollection/{documentId}').onUpdate(event => {
// code
});
```

`collection` and `doc` are methods within `firebase.firestore`.  To access them via `functions.firestore`, you must use `document`.

You can see a full list of Classes for [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Firestore) and the latest SDK for [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions)

### Update

I've been working on your code.  I've added in all of the dependencies and initialization, which I *assume* that you have in your code.  I can't see where you're using any data from Firestore in your IBM Watson request and I can't see how you're writing any of the returned data back to Firestore.  As I'm not familiar with your `request` method, I've commented it out, to give you what should be a working example of an update to Firestore and writes something back.  I also edited some of your code to make it more readable and changed the Cloud Functions code to reflect v1.0.0, released today (I've been testing it for a while) :)

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.getWatsonTokenFS = functions.firestore
  .document('User_Login_Event/{Toggle_Value}')
  .onUpdate((snap, context) => {

    let username = 'TDK';
    let password = 'swordfish';
    let url = `https://${username}:${password}@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api`;

    // request({url}, function (error, response, body) {
    // firestore.doc(`${IBM_Watson_Token}/${Token_Value}`).update('token');
    // });

    return firestore.doc(`IBM_Watson_Token/Token_Value`).update('token')
    .then(response => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, 'myCollection/{documentId}' is more clear than the documentation's 'users/{userId}'. But I'm still getting an error message when my function executes: "firebase.firestore is not a function". I edited my question to include my full code. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Hey @ThomasDavidKehoe I've updated my answer.  However, without seeing how you've defined certain things, I've had to guess at some stuff.

Comment: The difference between the previous version of Cloud FUnctions and 1.0.0 is swapping `event` for `snap` and `context`.  You can get the details of how to use the new version [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

Comment: Yes, I had the "require" and other header statements. Copying your code, admin.initializeApp(); throws an error: "Error: Invalid Firebase app options passed as the first argument to initializeApp() for the app named "[DEFAULT]". The "credential" property must be an object which implements the Credential interface." Changing that statement to "admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);" fixes that problem. I still get "TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function" with your code.

Comment: Can you check that you have up to date packages installed?

Comment: I have Firebase 4.12.1 in my index.html file. npm -v firebase-tools --> 5.8.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168239/discussion-between-thomas-david-kehoe-and-jason-berryman).

Comment: I found a small bug in my code and I've fixed it (answer updated).  `snap, context` was not wrapped in parentheses.  I created a project and deployed it here, to test it

Comment: I'm calling a function from my Android app successfully. However, I am unable to read from Firestore document without using one of the **triggers** as I'm looking to update the document in the reference defined with the given data I'm passing into the `onCall` function. All of the params I'm passing in work as expected and I'm using a `.get()` on the document reference.

Answer (score 4):

Now that Firebase has updated `firebase-admin` to 5.12.0 and `firebase-functions` to 1.0.1 my test function is working. The function that Jason Berryman wrote is correct except for two lines. Jason wrote:

```
.onUpdate((snap, context) => {
```

That should be

```
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
```

Secondly, Jason wrote:

```
return firestore.doc(`IBM_Watson_Token/Token_Value`).update('token')
```

The corrected line is:

```
return firestore.collection('IBM_Watson_Token').doc('Token_Value').update({
    token: 'newToken'
  })
```

I made two changes in Jason's code. First, I changed the location syntax; more on this below. Second, `update()` requires an object as the argument.

To show the syntax for locations, I wrote a simple Cloud Function that triggers when a value at a location in Cloud Firestore changes, and then writes a new value to a different location in Cloud Firestore. I removed the line `const firestore = admin.firestore();` to make the code more clear:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('triggerCollection/{documentID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  return admin.firestore().collection('writeCollection').doc('documentID').update({
    token: 'newValue'
  })
  .then(response => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
});
```

Let's compare three syntaxes for locations in Cloud Firestore. First, in the browser I use this syntax:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc('documentID')
```

Next, in a Cloud Function trigger I use this syntax:

```
functions.firestore.document('myCollection/{documentID}')
```

Third, in the Cloud Function return I use this syntax:

```
admin.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc('documentID')
```

The first and last lines are the same except that from the browser you call Firebase with `firebase`, when from the server you call Firebase using the `firebase-admin` Node package, here aliased to `admin`.

The middle line is different. It's calling Firebase using the `firebase-functions` Node package, here aliased to `functions`.

In other words, Firebase is called using different libraries, depending on whether you're calling from the browser or the server (e.g., a Cloud Function), and whether in a Cloud Function you're calling a trigger or a return.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions is triggered based on events happening in Firebase example in realtime database, authentication.

Cloud firestore is triggered based on events happening in Firestore which uses the concept of documents and collections.

As explained here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

The cloud firestore triggers are used when there is a change in a document.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used following

```
const getReceiverDataPromise = admin.firestore().doc('users/' + receiverUID).get();
const getSenderDataPromise = admin.firestore().doc('users/' + senderUID).get();

return Promise.all([getReceiverDataPromise, getSenderDataPromise]).then(results => {

        const receiver = results[0].data();
        console.log("receiver: ", receiver);

        const sender = results[1].data();
        console.log("sender: ", sender);

});
```